# How to make a Highcharts bar disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to think of a way where a user can click a button and cause a Highcharts bar to disappear.

For example, in my Highcharts code here:

```
$(function(){
  Highcharts.setOptions({
  colors:['#49acdd'],
  chart:{
    style: {
      fontFamily:'Helvetica',
      color:'#384044'
    }
  }
});

$("#chart").highcharts({
  chart: {
    type:'column',
    backgroundColor:'#158479'
  },
  title: {
    text: "Employer Organizations",
    style: {
      color: "#8A2BE2" //wmakes the text white
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    tickWidth: 1,
    labels: {
      style: {
        color: '#cc3737'
      }
    },
    categories:[
      'Educational and School-Based','Government Orgs','Charitable Foundation Orgs','Health-care Orgs','Market Research Orgs','Technology Firms','Human Service Orgs','Accounting/Finance Firms'
    ]
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth:0, //no gridlines
    title: {
      text:'',
      style:{
        color:'#fff'
      }
    },
    labels: {
      formatter:function(){
        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value,0,'', ' ,');//returns ex: 1000 to 1,000
      },
      style:{
        color:'#33FF00'
      }
    }
  },//end of y axis
  plotOptions:{
    column: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      pointPadding:0,//paddin between each column or bar
      groupPadding:0.1//Padding between each value groups, in x axis units
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: "Employer Organizations",
    data: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  }]
});
});
```

I know the "plotOptions.bar.events.click" exists for triggering click-based functions, but I'm unable to find a function that lets a Highchart bar disappear when clicked upon.

Comment: Can you be more specifica about it? Is it inside a web page or is it a JS app?

Comment: If you want to delete it .. on click of that bar, get the data-id of the bar and update the data of the chart removing the selected data-id

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/mgpz9p32/  may help. click on column to delete

Comment: If you do not want to remove point, you can hide it instead. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qxfm72r/.

Comment: @DanieleMartini Hi daniele Im sorry about the late response, yes it is a JS app.

Comment: @Deep3015 Thank you! I wish there was a way to upvote comments or mark them as best answer, yours would be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disappear particular column in highcharts. Modify your `plotOptions`

```
plotOptions: {
 column: {
    borderRadius: 4,
    pointPadding: 0, //paddin between each column or bar
    groupPadding: 0.1 //Padding between each value groups, in x axis units
  },
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          if (!confirm('Do you really want to remove this column?')) {
            return false;
          } else {
            this.remove();
          }
        }
      },

    }
  }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgpz9p32/) Demo